# Do we keep levels, gils and items when going back with "Calling Umbra"?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm at level 35 and already at the final chapter. I see high leveled daemons and I'm not sure that I'm supposed to be here underleveled like I am.

Does calling Umbra will help me raise my level and keep my items/gil aquired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you keep everything going back. You can go back, buy new stuff, and come back with the new stuff as well.

It's useful to level up / power up.

Comment: Ok thanks because I was like screwed and not able to finish the game otherwise. I understand why they have added this feature now.